# Calculating percentage on Grafana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I've got two queries A and B on Grafana with elastic search as the data source. Is there anyway to implement a third query which shows the percentage (A/B),
For example count of query A is 5 and count of query B is 10 , I want a third column stating 50% in the dashboard itself .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a plugin called [MetaQueries](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/goshposh-metaqueries-datasource) for Grafana, clone this repo into your grafana plugins directory (it is usually on /var/lib/grafana/plugins)

```
git clone git@github.com:GoshPosh/grafana-meta-queries.git
sudo service grafana-server restart
```

Then you can do an arithmetic function on query C to count query A and B, in this case A/B * 100